# I am using Kali Linux, but however, I want to know how to switch my normal user account into root admin?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, root

I want to know how to switch my normal user account into root admin?

For example, when I log into my account I cannot modify and save `sources.list` from `/etc/apt/folder` nor can I get an update for `apt-get update` or even `apt-get upgrade`.

Is there anyway possible I can convert my normal user account to admin (root)?

Comment: I'll jump in and say what many are thinking. If you can't figure out su, root, or sodu, you may want to start with a beginner's guide to Linux and a educational style os

Comment: Pretty much what @Tim just said too. Just Google a root command in your Linux platform. `sudo {command}` is mainly used in Debian based OS.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
su -
```

with password toor

Answer (score 1):

Go to your account icon and log out, then you can log back in with another account